# PostgreSQL: NULL value in foreign key column

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following tables (simplified):

```sql
CREATE TABLE quotations (
  receipt_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE order_confirmations (
  receipt_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  fk_quotation_receipt_id bigint REFERENCES quotations (receipt_id)
);
```

My problem now reads as follows:

I have orders which relate to previous quotations (which is fine 'cause I can attach such an order to the quotation referenced by using the FK field), but I also have placed-from-scratch orders **without** a matching quotation. The FK field would then be NULL, if the database let me, of course. Unfortunately, I get an **error** when trying to set `fk_quotation_receipt_id` to NULL in an INSERT statement because of a **violated** foreign key constraint.

When designing these tables I was still using PgSQL 8.2, which allowed NULL values. Now I've got 9.1.6, which does not allow for this.

What I wish is an **optional (or nullable)** foreign key constraint `order_confirmations` (`fk_quotation_receipt_id`) → `quotations (receipt_id)`. I can't find any hints in the official PgSQL docs, and similar issues posted by other users are already quite old.

Thank you for any useful hints.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Works for me in 9.3 after correcting a missing comma. I'm sure it will work also in 9.1

```
create table quotations (
    receipt_id bigint not null primary key
);

create table order_confirmations (
    receipt_id bigint not null primary key,
    fk_quotation_receipt_id bigint references quotations (receipt_id)
);

insert into order_confirmations (receipt_id, fk_quotation_receipt_id) values 
    (1, null);
```

[Confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835406/1175496) will include:

```
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: The missing comma was not the issue (I simply forgot it when copying, grrrrr). It turned out that the client code added a 0 instead of a NULL, and as this was a prepared statement, I did not see it in the logs. Nevertheless thanx a lot for your answer.

Comment: This was super helpful - I was looking around everywhere why null values are not accepted, all the while I was just trying to update the field to "" instead of null.

Answer (score 4):

I keep trying to remember this case every now and then. So following atomic case helps me to remember:

```sql
drop table if exists t2;
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key
);

create table t2 (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    t1_id int references t1(id)
);

insert into t1 values (1);

insert into t2 values (1, 1);    -- OK, 1 exists so accepted
insert into t2 values (2, null); -- OK, null is accepted
insert into t2 values (3, 2);    -- NOK, 2 is not accepted
```

If you want to forbid the null case, then it is not related with foreign key but with the declaration of the column **(observe the new coming `not null` part)**:

```sql
...
create table t2 (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    t1_id int not null references t1(id)
);
...
```

***PS: Capital letter reserved words reduce SQL's readability. Please use small letters.***